# Error will came after create a new activity in android as named FinalActivity

Tags: java, android

Worked in android studio. I created a new activity which named as FinalActivity. After Creating activity,i'm check my remaining all java file (i.e. MyActivity.java). Error Occur in the file. The R.id.Buuton which indicates the R in Red colour. While click that, the error mentioned **'cannot resolve the Symbol R'**. I just leave that. Then i deleted the entire project created new one, as same as follow the about steps. After creating the final activity above the same error occur again.
**Is any problem to create a activity name as FinalActivity**

Comment: please provide the whole code of your activity, thanks

Comment: I don´t think so, but this can be the cause of so many mistakes. Please post Your relevant code and xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found it...

Used the wizard to create a new Activity named FinalActivity. This is a verbatim copy of the code:

```
package com.mycompany.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class FinalActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_final);
        findViewById(R.id.lala);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.final, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

If you rebuild, and check this part:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.final, menu);
```

you are getting this error:
Error:error: invalid symbol: 'final'

That's because `final` is a Java keyword. You should rename the `final.xml` file in the "menu" package

Comment: So it is not necessary to import `R` anymore?

Comment: Seems like, since R is not generated due to errors, it cannot be imported

Comment: And how should your first code work if `R` was not imported, but used?

Comment: Because I didn't used the wizard back then. Just created a regular Java class and extended the `Activity` class. Your comment made me realize it was strange that no R import was needed ;)

Comment: So you're saying that your code compiled correctly? To be honest, I doubt that.

Answer (score 0):

Please Make sure you are targeting the correct version of android with the available sdk tools.
If you target high versions of android and Not having the required tools this errors shows up.
I had this kind of error like a month back when i targeted to kitkat wear without downloading the SDK tools .

Goto

> Window>Android Sdk Manager > Install latest sdk build tools

OR

Goto

> ProjectName>Project Manifest

and decrease the android version to the version you are having ..

Hope this helps..
All the best....